# java spring with call different selector

Tags: java, html, spring, web-services, thymeleaf

I have this code html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>            
      <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${person}">
            <select id="person" th:field="*{name}">
                    <option th:each="p : ${list}" th:value="${p.getName()}"  th:text="${p.getName()}"></option>
        </select>    
     <input type="submit" onclick="cargaDatos()" value="CargarDatos"/>  
     </form>  
    <div th:fragment="selector">        
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/prueba}" th:object="${prueba}">
    <select id="prueba">
        <option th:each="p : ${lista}" th:value="${p.getName()}"  th:text="${p.getName()}"></option>
    </select>    
    </form>
    </div>    
    <button type="submit">informe</button>
    <script type="text/javascript"> function cargaDatos() {
     $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
     url: "http://localhost:8080/prueba", success: 
   function(data){ alert("Ejecutado correctamente"); }, error: function  
   (data){ alert("Error en la ejecucion"); } }); } </script>   
 </body>
 </html>
```

And this code in Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String showForm(Person person, Model model) { 

System.out.println("/"); 
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>(); 
Person p1 = new Person(); 
p1.setName("John"); 
p1.setAge(46); 
Person p2 = new Person(); 
p2.setName("Helen"); 
p2.setAge(34); 
list.add(p1); 
list.add(p2); 
model.addAttribute("list",list); 
return "form"; 
} 
@RequestMapping(value="/prueba", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String showForm(Person person, Prueba prueba, Model model) { 

System.out.println("/prueba"); 
List<Prueba> lista = new ArrayList<Prueba>(); 
Prueba p11 = new Prueba(); 
p11.setName("prueba1"); 
Prueba p22 = new Prueba(); 
p22.setName("prueba2"); 
lista.add(p11); 
lista.add(p22); 
model.addAttribute("lista",lista); 
return "form :: selector"; 
} 

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String checkPersonInfo(Person person1) throws InterruptedException { 

persona = person1.getName(); 
    System.out.printf("1-el nombre seleccionado es: %s \n", persona); 
    return "redirect:/prueba"; 
} 

@RequestMapping(value="/prueba", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String checkPersonInfo(Prueba prueba) { 
    System.out.printf("2-el nombre seleccionado es: %s \n",      prueba.getName()); 
    return "redirect:/prueba"; 
}
```

And I want when the user press bottom, the selector 2 show options in function option selection in selector 1. But I want the screen show always selectors.

What is the problem? I don't know how I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess you want to fill the selector with data after clicking the button but you dont wanna reload the page ?

The problem is that you bind the input submit button to a function, so if you click on it you will submit the data and go to another page.

I suggest you to create another button and bind the function to it:

```
<button type="button" onclick="cargaDatos()">Your button text</button>
```

The javaScript function:

```
function cargaDatos(){ 
   var link = /*[[@/prueba]]*/ 'prueba';
   $("#selectorDiv").load(link);
};
```

And the html selector:

```
 <div id="selectorDiv">
    <select id="prueba">
       <option th:each="p : ${lista}" th:value="${p.getName()}"  th:text="${p.getName()}"></option>
    </select>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I want this. I want that when sumit buttom, refresh this second selector. I make other buttom wtih that funcionallity and I tell you

Comment: And since I see you are using thymeleaf instead of this: var link = "http://localhost:8080/yourapplication/prueba"; write : var link = /*[[@/prueba]]*/ 'prueba';

Comment: I have a problem with your solution, I need "save" the  person select in selector1 before then I update selector2, because selector2 is a list of database. How I can do this?, I dont want add other buttom